# Web socket message size header

Tags: c#, websocket

I am implementing a web socket communication and wondered if it would be possible to get the whole message size and allocate appropriate buffer for it before receiving the message.
I was thinking of a similar concept that i use with normal Sockets where the message is prefixed with the size but since the web socket protocol itself already have that info and it would be wiser to use it.

I am using System.Net.WebSockets implementation.

Comment: You need to sent the message size at the beginning of the message to be able to do what you are requesting.  Then the receive end extracts the size and then reads the rest of the message.

Comment: Thanks. So you would say that this is a same common approach for web sockets?

Comment: Any communication protocol can include a byte count at beginning of a message.  Whenever you send data the receiving end needs to know where the end of each message occurs.  You can use combination of the following 3 methods 1) Terminate each message with known character which is not part of the message  like a return 2) Add a byte count at beginning of message 3) Use fixed length messages.